# How to build gcc that enforces packing in structures

Tags: gcc, arm

We are using gcc 4.4.6 for ARM (patched with rtems 4.10 stuff). It was built ages ago and there is no documentation how it was done. It enforces packing in structures. We need to modify newlib and rebuild gcc. First I built the toolchain (newlib was not modified yet) and tried to run application in our system. It did not work properly because of the data alignment in structures. I made sure that I passed the same options to configure as with the old gcc (I retrieved them by running gcc -v --help). Does anyone know how to build gcc with enforced packing in structure. The -fpack-struct option or packed attribute are not a solution for me.
cheers,
Marek

Comment: what about `specs`? gcc -dumpspecs > specs

Comment: You can build your own GCC with crosstool-ng and customize it however you want. Fairly trivial. http://crosstool-ng.github.io

Comment: why are you using structures across compile domains?

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux specs are identical in both cases:

Comment: @old_timer what do you mean?

Comment: Other than saving space there is no reason to pack structures.  If crossing compile domains is the reason you will always be plagued with this issue.

Comment: gcc for arm (and others) will properly align structures so there are no alignment issues, unless you try to pack them and then you may have issues...

Comment: Please provide an example that represents the problem.

Comment: @old_timer I have to pack structures for backward compatibility and there is no other option for me. There are number of applications that have already been used for years and they were built with packed structures. Applications built with the default alignment don't work in our system. It seems like -mstructure-size-boundary=8 option added to CFLAGS does the whole trick. Somehow it was embedded in the previous toolchain. None of the specs we use have that option.

Comment: you could go without structures then...or have a function that copies the data into structures.  so there WAS another option for you (that was very portable going forward)...this will happen again, dont worry...you will have to go through this exercise (until you make it portable).

Comment: post your own answer then and check it or edit your question to show that you came up with an answer.

Comment: @old_timer Generally I agree with you on portability importance, but not in this case. There will never be need to make our software portable. It's not going to be used outside our system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to initialize mstructure-size-boundary option (in  gcc-4.4.6/gcc/config.arm/arm.opt) with 8:

```
mstructure-size-boundary=
Target RejectNegative Joined Var(structure_size_string) Init("8")
```

and rebuild the toolchain. mstructure-size-boundary specifies the minimum bit alignment of structures. The default value for ARM platform is 32.
Cheers,
Marek

Comment: You'll better build a newer version of GCC, i.e. [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/). It has evolved a lot.

Comment: you have disabled alignment checking in the cpu and can tolerate the performance hit?

Comment: @old_timer that's the trade off I was prepared to accept from the start.